# Why is this simple minitest failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I'm new to testing rails applications as I usually just do manual testing... but I'm trying to do it the right way this time.

Why is this basic test failing?

```
test "once you go to to app you are asked to sign in" do
  get "/"
  assert_redirected_to "/users/sign_in"
  assert_select "title", "Home Sign-In"
end
```

The first assertion is successful but not the second. The title seems correct when I view source.

```
<title>Home Sign-In</title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have redirect call in your controller method it is not acturally rendered. That's why you can't use `assert_select`.

You may try to divide your test case into two:

```
test "once you go to to app you are asked to sign in" do
  get "/"
  assert_redirected_to "/users/sign_in"
end

test "sign in page title is correct" do
  get "/users/sign_in"
  assert_select "title", "Home Sign-In"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pavel is right. 
A simple way to check the response after get request is **@response.body**.
So in your case

```
test "once you go to to app you are asked to sign in" do
  get "/"
  assert_redirected_to "/users/sign_in"
  byebug #print @response.body here. At this point @response.body will
  # be "You are being redirected to /users/sign_in".
  assert_select "title", "Home Sign-In"
 end
```

So you can modify it as **Pavel** has suggested

```
test "sign in page title is correct" do
  get "/users/sign_in"
  assert_select "title", "Home Sign-In"
end
```